# Jquery sticky th

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I'm working on a sticky header for tables that are placed in the middle and towards the bottom of the page. I have this working, for the most part, but I cannot figure out how to properly position the header.

I've tried fixed position, but it has an issue with the scrolling outside the box, absolute messes with the headers width and sticky seems to insert the header into the table and mess with formatting.

Any ideas?

```
    function stickyTableHead(tableID) {
  var $tmain = $(tableID);
  var $parent = $(tableID).parent();
  var pos = $parent.offset().top + $tmain.find(">thead").height();
  var $tScroll = $tmain.children("thead")
    .clone()
    .wrapAll('<table id="tScroll" />')
    .parent()
    .addClass($(tableID).attr("class"))
    .css("position", "sticky")
    .css("top", 0)
    .css("display", "none")
    .prependTo($tmain);


  $($parent).scroll(function() {
    var dataScroll = $tScroll.data("scroll");
    dataScroll = dataScroll || false;
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= $tmain.find(">thead").height()) {
      if (!dataScroll) {
        $tScroll
          .data("scroll", true)
          .show()
          .find("th").each(function() {
            $(this).width($tmain.find(">thead>tr>th").eq($(this).index()).width());
          });
      }
    } else {
      if (dataScroll) {
        $tScroll
          .data("scroll", false)
          .hide();
      }
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  stickyTableHead('#transactionT');
});
```

JsFiddle for example because it's too long for the text editor here
https://jsfiddle.net/zazvorniki/7g245fr6/54/

Comment: I was creating something like that and the way I've created it was two tables one for header and one for table, scrollbar was on container and header was sticky. There was one problem with this solution if cells where not fixed size, in my code I needed to get the size of each column in table and header add apply bigger size to both header and table cells, so they were the same widths, and need to recalculate the sized on window resize (where I've first removed the inline width style to make them resize and then set the width again).

Comment: @jcubic, that's an interesting solution. Unfortunately, I can't do that in this environment.  The tables are being created dynamically and I don't have access to that. I can only handle them after the fact in the browser.

Comment: You're applying jQuery on table so you can modify it with jQuery. This is how I was doing it also in my case the table were generated in R shiny framework, and were updating dynamically. The solution I was using was mutationObserver that was triggering when table was updated and it triggered jQuery code that was patching the table. removing first row and puting it into separated table. Just like any other jQuery table plugin do.

Comment: @jcubic There is other logic built into these tables though such as sorting that depend on the headers being a part of the table. So while theoretically I could in this case its not really a viable solution.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have sticky header with single table with just CSS but I may be wrong. So if you need to have sorting or other feature that on original table you will need to recreate that feature in your own table, or make it work with patched table. For instance hide first row instead of removing it on on click of sticky header you trigger click on hidden row cell.

Comment: To have something like this it's too much code to give here, and you will need to know exact requirements.

Comment: @jcubic, it's not just sorting that is the issue. There are some complex actions that need to stay intact and I cannot recreate. The above code 99% works, it's just that little part that is not so I'm really aiming to try and resolve that if at all possible. I know I have seen something similar working, I just cannot for the life of me find it.

Comment: If you have lot of code that do other stuff you will need to modify that code in order to have sticky header, change the structure and fix other code is it all works. I don't think it's possible other way, having complex JS table and need sticky header for it. Without modifying code that generate that interactivity nothing you can do.

Comment: @jcubic I cannot modify that code. It touches too many things in too many different parts of the application. I can only modify this little part to add a sticky header to three of the forty tables that us the same code.

Comment: The only solution then is to clone the header make it sticky with CSS hide original header and listen for each event on clone header and trigger events to orginal hidden header. You can call it event proxy. You will need to read the code for the table and check for which events the code is listening and proxy those events. If you can't do that then you can't have sticky header.